# Trying to change shortcut target property with C

Tags: c

I made a C program to change the target property of Chrome shortcut to load it with a extension that I made. The code works if I use `char newTargetPath[200] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"";` it doesn't work if I use `char newTargetPath[200] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --load-extension=C:\\path\\to\\extension";` How can I successfully execute this code with the `--load-extension` flag? This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShObjIdl.h>
#include <ShlGuid.h>
#include <ObjBase.h>
#include <combaseapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Replace with the path of your shortcut file
    char shortcutPath[200] = "C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\chrome.lnk";
    // Replace with the path of the new target file
    char newTargetPath[200] = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --load-extension=C:\\path\\to\\extension";

    // Create an instance of the IShellLink interface
    IShellLink* shellLink;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (void**)&shellLink);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Create an instance of the IPersistFile interface
        IPersistFile* persistFile;
        hr = shellLink->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&persistFile);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Convert the shortcut path to Unicode
            wchar_t shortcutPathW[MAX_PATH];
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, shortcutPath, -1, shortcutPathW, MAX_PATH);

            // Load the existing shortcut file
            hr = persistFile->Load(shortcutPathW, STGM_READ);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // Set the new target file path
                wchar_t newTargetPathW[MAX_PATH];
                MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, newTargetPath, -1, newTargetPathW, MAX_PATH);
                hr = shellLink->SetPath(newTargetPathW);

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // Save the modified shortcut file
                    hr = persistFile->Save(shortcutPathW, TRUE);

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        printf("Shortcut target modified successfully.\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Error saving modified shortcut file. HRESULT: 0x%x\n", hr);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Error setting shortcut target. HRESULT: 0x%x\n", hr);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error loading shortcut file. HRESULT: 0x%x\n", hr);
            }

            persistFile->Release();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error querying IPersistFile interface. HRESULT: 0x%x\n", hr);
        }

        shellLink->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error creating IShellLink instance. HRESULT: 0x%x\n", hr);
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use program arguments in `SetPath`. A path is a path, not a command. Use `SetArguments` method to set program arguments.